# fastapi azure auth redirect URI mismatch error

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, fastapi, azure-authentication

I keep getting below AADSTS50011 error even though I have already specified the correct redirect URI for the relevant app. Can you please provide guidance on resolving this issue? code snippet is attached below. Thank you.

[image]
[image]

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Security
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from fastapi_azure_auth import SingleTenantAzureAuthorizationCodeBearer
from pydantic.v1 import BaseSettings
from router.flight_router import flight_router
from router.user_router import user_router

class Settings(BaseSettings):
BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:8000']
OPENAPI_CLIENT_ID: str = "***"
APP_CLIENT_ID: str = "***"
TENANT_ID: str = "***"
SCOPE_DESCRIPTION: str = "***"

@property
def SCOPES(self) -> dict:
    return {
        'api://**/**': '**',
    }

settings = Settings()

app = FastAPI(
swagger_ui_oauth2_redirect_url='/docs',
swagger_ui_init_oauth={
    'usePkceWithAuthorizationCodeGrant': True,
    'clientId': "***",
},
)

@app.on_event('startup')
async def load_config() -> None:
"""
Load OpenID config on startup.
"""
await azure_scheme.openid_config.load_config()


@app.get("/", dependencies=[Security(azure_scheme)])
async def welcome():
return {"message": "Welcome to Flight Reservation System"}
```

Comment: For the purposes of the registered redirect URI - localhost is not 127.0.0.1

Comment: Hi @PGHE , can you please elaborate? 127.0.0.1:8000 is what I use as localhost

Comment: As in the actual string of characters 'localhost' is not the same string as '127.0.0.1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the comment @PGHE.

I followed this [Documentation](https://intility.github.io/fastapi-azure-auth/single-tenant/azure_setup) for creating this project.

I faced an issue with authorization, so I used the command below to run the project.

```
 uvicorn main:app --host localhost --port 8000
```

This helped me get the URL with localhost instead of the following URL: `http://127.0.0.1:8000`.

**main.py**

```py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Security
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from fastapi_azure_auth import SingleTenantAzureAuthorizationCodeBearer
from pydantic import AnyHttpUrl
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings

class Settings(BaseSettings):
    BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS: list[str | AnyHttpUrl] = ['http://localhost:8000']
    OPENAPI_CLIENT_ID: str = "OpenApiIdClientId"
    APP_CLIENT_ID: str = "AppClientId"
    TENANT_ID: str = "TenantId"
    SCOPE_DESCRIPTION: str = "scopeDescription"
      
    @property
    def SCOPE_NAME(self) -> str:
        return f'api://{self.APP_CLIENT_ID}/{self.SCOPE_DESCRIPTION}'  
    @property
    def SCOPES(self) -> dict:
        return {
            self.SCOPE_NAME: self.SCOPE_DESCRIPTION,
        }
   
    @property
    def OPENAPI_AUTHORIZATION_URL(self) -> str:
        return f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{self.TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"
   
    @property
    def OPENAPI_TOKEN_URL(self) -> str:
        return f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{self.TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token"

    class Config:
        env_file = '.env'
        env_file_encoding = 'utf-8'
        case_sensitive = True
settings = Settings()
app = FastAPI(
    swagger_ui_oauth2_redirect_url='/oauth2-redirect',
    swagger_ui_init_oauth={
        'usePkceWithAuthorizationCodeGrant': True,
        'clientId': settings.OPENAPI_CLIENT_ID,
        'scopes': settings.SCOPE_NAME,
    },
)
if settings.BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS:
    app.add_middleware(
        CORSMiddleware,
        allow_origins=[str(origin) for origin in settings.BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS],
        allow_credentials=True,
        allow_methods=['*'],
        allow_headers=['*'],
    )
azure_scheme = SingleTenantAzureAuthorizationCodeBearer(
    app_client_id=settings.APP_CLIENT_ID,
    tenant_id=settings.TENANT_ID,
    scopes=settings.SCOPES,
)
@app.on_event('startup')
async def load_config() -> None:
    """
    Load OpenID config on startup.
    """
    await azure_scheme.openid_config.load_config()

@app.get("/", dependencies=[Security(azure_scheme)])
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run('main:app', reload=True)
```

I added the following URI in the App Redirect URI as shown below:

[image]

[image]

**Output**:

[image]

With the output URL above, I clicked on the **Authorize** button.

[image]

I got the page below and clicked on the **Authorize** button.

[image]

It redirected me to pick an account for signing in. Then, I selected my account as shown below:

[image]

[image]

Finally, I got the output below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Aslesha! I was also able to resolve the error by changing the redirect URI to '/oauth2-redirect'. That's another solution if anyone encounters the same error :)